# How can I ignore "Process Crashed" during JUnit testing

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I have an JUnit test with a method that I KNOW will fail out with

```
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process 
crashed.'
```

This is expected as part of a process that "crashes" and relaunches the app. I can't touch the code where this crash happens, so I have to accept it.

I want to run this `@Test`, and when it inevitably crashes, pass the test anyway, and continue on to the next test.

I have already tried to surround the code with

```
try {} catch() {}
```

I have tried using (expected = Exception), and throws Exception

I have tried this

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    rogueMethod();
}
```

Expected result:

The JUnit test runs without any failure at all, despite the process crash.

Actual result: The test fails every-time, and the rest of the tests do not continue as a result.

If there is no way to ignore this in the code, I at least want a way to run this before every test starts, throw out the failure result, then continue on. Essentially this method changes the state of the app.

Comment: add @Ignore to the testcase, so it will not be executed

Comment: I want the test case to be executed, I just don't want the result (crash) to affect anything else.

Comment: Why it makes sence to execute a testcase that fails? How you run your junit tests? can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: So basically this method puts the app in a certain state. If I were to do this manually it would easily 20x the work. Otherwise I can use espresso/junit to hit a button in the app that does it for me. When hitting this button, the app crashes itself but then relaunches just fine in its new state right after.

The downside is that this causes my tests to fail thereafter.

Comment: I can simply run the Junit tests with espresso in Intellij with the run function. But they also run in Jenkins with Firebase. So it will need to work in there eventually as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator)? In its documentation it states that:

> **Crashes are isolated**. Even if one test crashes, it takes down only its own instance of Instrumentation, so the other tests in your suite still run.

I suppose the crash you're seeing happens in the app under test, that is, the crash takes down the instrumentation with it when it happens. Using Test Orchestrator would supposedly let the subsequent tests run even if this happens.

Comment: This looks promising! I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I got Test Orchestrator running, and confirmed it is running, but it still fails out in a similar way. Is there some flag or something I need to set in order for the tests to continue?

Comment: That's odd, isolated mode should be the default: https://github.com/android/android-test/blob/master/runner/android_test_orchestrator/java/androidx/test/orchestrator/AndroidTestOrchestrator.java#L470. I see that you're not the only one experiencing this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567314/androids-test-orchestrator-is-stopping-on-crashed-test. However I couldn't find any reported bugs in the Android issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=orchestrator%20process%20crash, nor on Github at https://github.com/android/android-test/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=process+crash

Comment: It seems the issue is I have to use androidx, but I cannopt get androidx to sync with gradle... so there is another issue.

Comment: Oh, post back if you're unable to solve it. I made a migration to androidx just a few weeks ago.

Comment: I actually got it to work in firebase using the --use-orchestrator flag, but it did not ignore the failure at all! Same issue.

Comment: I think I need to set up a minimal project to try this out. Is there anything special about this app state and the crash? What type of Exception/Error is being thrown?